# Python Regex to extract text between numbers

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract the text between digits. For example, if  have text such as the following

```
1964 ORDINARY shares
EXECUTORS OF JOANNA C RICHARDSON
100 ORDINARY shares 
TG MARTIN
C MARTIN
7500 ORDINARY shares 
ARCO LIMITED
```

I want to produce a list of 3 elements, where each element is the text between the numbers including the first number but not the end number, and the final element in the list where there is no end number

```
[
'1964 ORDINARY shares \nEXECUTORS OF JOANNA C RICHARDSON',
'100 ORDINARY shares \nTG MARTIN\nC MARTIN\n',
'7500 ORDINARY shares\nARCO LIMITED'
]
```

I tried doing this

```
regex = r'\d(.+?)\d
re.findall(regex, a, re.DOTALL)
```

but it returned

```
['9',
 ' ORDINARY shares\nEXECUTORS OF JOANNA C RICHARDSON\n',
 '0 ORDINARY shares\nTG MARTIN\nC MARTIN\n',
 '0']
```

Comment: Try `regex = r'\d+\D+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to achieve this.

```
import re

text = """1964 ORDINARY shares
EXECUTORS OF JOANNA C RICHARDSON
100 ORDINARY shares 
TG MARTIN
C MARTIN
7500 ORDINARY shares 
ARCO LIMITED"""

# Use regex to find the text between digits
pattern = r'\d+.*?(?=\d|$)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `\d(.+?)\d` matches at least 3 characters, where the outer 2 digits are matched, and the inner part is captured in group 1 (where `(.+?)` matches at least 1 character)

You get those results because you are using a capture group with [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), which returns the value of the capture group.

So for example in `1964` you match `196`, where `9` is captured in group 1 and that is the first value in your result.

There is a downvoted and removed answer by [markalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21363224/markalex) and a comment by [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) that hold a key to use a pattern without `re.DOTALL` and a non greedy quantifier.

```
\b\d+\b\D*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b\d+\b` Match 1+ digits between word boundaries to prevent a partial word match
- `\D*` Match optional chars other than digits, including newlines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0bnyIX/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/l53V8y)

If the matches should be from the start of the string and be followed by a whitespace char, you might also consider using an anchor with `re.M` for multiline

```
^\d+\s\D*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SedLRP/1) | [Pyton demo](https://ideone.com/NkrG47)